# How to manage rollbacks on spring cloud config

Tags: spring, version-control, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have a spring cloud config repository, a server and a client. Originally the functionality expected is to be able to reload properties without stopping the running service. Now if there is a rollback on the client's end, how do i ensure that it picks up an older version of the property file?

I've tried specifying the spring.cloud.config.label value but if i put in a specific tag or version, wouldn't i lose the intended functionality of the client tracking changes on the repo?